# Can i use three "OR" logical operators for comparing with one variable in PHP

Tags: php

I am thinking if it is possible to use like this in php.

```
if(date("j") =='Monday'||'Wednesday'||'Friday'){
     /*do something*/
} else{ /*do something*/ }
```

If it is wrong what is the best way to compare date("j") with weekdays.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you have one variable you have nothing to compare aginst with a **binary** operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in_array` function of PHP.

```
if (in_array($date("j"), array("monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"))){//dosomthing
     }else{
         //do something
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this conclusion as I understood,

You want to compare day with your values,

Try this:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//echo date("l",strtotime($date));
if (in_array(date("l",strtotime($date)), array("Monday", "Sunday", "Saturday"))){
    echo "value in array";
 }else{
     echo "value is not in array";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but in a proper way like:

```
if( date("j") == 'Monday' || date("j") == 'Wednesday' || date("j") == 'Friday' ){
```

**Explanation:** You have to check each pair individually.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know that.But is there any way to use `date("j")` once not multiple times??

Comment: Why? Any specific requirement ?